# Blackberry - Place one invisible png bitmap above another as a new Bitmap/Image

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, blackberry-jde

I have a PNG image that is mostly invisble and contains some watermarks we will want to apply to another image.

I have imported this PNG into a Bitmap object.  I have imported the second image, taken with the device camera, as a second Bitmap object.

How do I overlay the PNG bitmap above the second one, retaining the PNG transparancy and store the resulting image as a new bitmap?

I need to store the results as I will be passing this final bitmap to a webservice in a byte array converted to a base64 string.

I have used this before however the blending changes the opacity of the images, this is not what I want, i want both images to be full 100% opacity, with the invisble PNG ontop...basically I want to make a frame onto a bitmap and store that as a new image.:

```java
public static Bitmap blend( Bitmap bi1, Bitmap bi2, double weight )
{
    int width = bi1.getWidth();
    int height = bi1.getHeight();
    Bitmap bi3 = new Bitmap(width, height);
    int[] rgbim1 = new int[width];
    int[] rgbim2 = new int[width];
    int[] rgbim3 = new int[width];
    for (int row = 0; row &lt; height; row++)
    {
        bi1.getARGB(rgbim1,0,width,0,row, width,1);
        bi2.getARGB(rgbim2,0,width,0,row, width,1);
        for (int col = 0; col &lt; width; col++)
        {
            int rgb1 = rgbim1[col];
            int a1 = (rgb1 &gt;&gt; 24) & 255;
            int r1 = (rgb1 &gt;&gt; 16) & 255;
            int g1 = (rgb1 &gt;&gt; 8) & 255;
            int b1 = rgb1 & 255;
            int rgb2 = rgbim2[col];
            int a2 = (rgb2 &gt;&gt; 24) & 255;
            int r2 = (rgb2 &gt;&gt; 16) & 255;
            int g2 = (rgb2 &gt;&gt; 8) & 255;
            int b2 = rgb2 & 255;
            int a3 = (int) (a1 * weight + a2 * (1.0 - weight));
            int r3 = (int) (r1 * weight + r2 * (1.0 - weight));
            int g3 = (int) (g1 * weight + g2 * (1.0 - weight));
            int b3 = (int) (b1 * weight + b2 * (1.0 - weight));
            rgbim3[col] = (a3 &lt;&lt; 24) | (r3 &lt;&lt; 16) | (g3 &lt;&lt; 8) | b3;
        }
        bi3.setARGB(rgbim3, 0, width, 0, row,width, 1);
    }
    return bi3;
}
```

Comment: Create a `Graphics` instance from the first `Bitmap`, and on that `Graphics` instance paint the second `Bitmap` (transparent one).

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by creating a manager. Draw first image using managers paint method & add second(Watermark image) to it as a Bitmap Field . It will look like image over image.